# Spring Boot REST method not allowed

Tags: rest, http, spring-boot, servlets

I'm trying to implement a method that will allow users (including anonymous) to read reviews about certain items. I want to use two path variables so I don't repeat myself with the code. That's how the Controller method looks like:

```
@RestController("/reviews")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReviewController {


    @Autowired
    private ReviewService reviewService;

    @GetMapping("/{type}/{id}")
    public ReviewDTO readReview(@PathVariable String type, @PathVariable long id) {
        return reviewService.readReview(type, id);
    }
```

Each type has its own entity, so I want to use the type variable to determine, which repository should be used. Here's the implementation of the ReviewService.readReview method:

```
public ReviewDTO readReview(String type, long id) {
        switch (type) {
            case "rides":
                return new RideReviewDTO(findRideReview(id));
            case "beacons":
                return new TransceiverReviewDTO(findTransceiverReview(id));
            case "backpacks":
                return null;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

When I'm running tests, the request looks exacly as it should:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /reviews/rides/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}
             Body = null
```

I'm getting an error though. This is the response I'm getting when trying to perform this request in Postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-11-20T07:08:39.145+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    "path": "/api/reviews/rides/1"
}
```

And this is the full reponse I get from test MockMvc:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 405
    Error message = Request method 'GET' not supported
          Headers = {Allow=[POST], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, when trying to debug, the method in the controller isn't even reached. That's how I configured my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PowderizeUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .headers().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users", "/users/confirm/**", "/users/forgotPassword").anonymous()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/reviews/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .logout().permitAll().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

**EDIT**

The answer given by @Alien was correct one, but there was also one more issue - in the security configuration method, the pattern `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/reviews/*").permitAll()` was also bad. there should be `/reviews/**`, otherwise the requests would not include the below directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Change

```
@RestController("/reviews")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReviewController
```

to

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/reviews")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReviewController
```

by specifying the base url in @RequestMapping instead of @RestController.